# @XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, xml-attribute

how to pick the value of an attribute 'name' which is a  PriceEventName class type   in the below case, FYI if i put @XmlAttribute above it this is turn out to an exception "an error @XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML"
I looking heavily on the internet but I didn't find something similar to my case

```
PriceEvent class

package somepackage
import ...
import 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

    public class PriceEvent {
        @XmlElement(name="Message",namespace="someValue")
        private String color;

        private PriceEventName name;// this is an attribute 
        .
        .
    }
```

PriceEventName class

```
Imports ...

public class PriceEventName {

    public static final int PRICEUPDATE_TYPE = 0;
    public static final PriceEventName PRICEUPDATE = new PriceEventName(PRICEUPDATE_TYPE, "X-mas");
    private static java.util.Hashtable _memberTable = init();
    private static java.util.Hashtable init() {
        Hashtable members = new Hashtable();
        members.put("X-mas", PRICEUPDATE);
        return members;
    }

    private final int type;
    private java.lang.String stringValue = null;

        public PriceEventName(final int type, final java.lang.String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.stringValue = value;
    }

    public static PriceEventName valueOf(final java.lang.String string) {
        java.lang.Object obj = null;
        if (string != null) {
            obj = _memberTable.get(string);
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            String err = "" + string + " is not a valid PriceEventName";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(err);
        }
        return (PriceEventName) obj;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the Java class definition of PriceEventName? Attributes need to have types such as String, int, boolean, etc, i.e., only what can be written as an XML attribute. Possibly you may have to define an adapter.

Comment: @peter  here we go i've added the class definition, may I have your opinion please

Comment: You'll need to use an adapter, mapping a String like "X-mas" to a PriceEventName, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you declare the field as an attribute with an adapter:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PenAdapter.class)
@XmlAttribute 
protected PriceEventName name;
public PriceEventName getName() { return name; }
public void setName(PriceEventName value) { this.name = value; }
```

Add you'll need to add a getter to PriceEventName:

```
public String getStringValue(){ return stringValue; }
```

And here is the adapter class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class PenAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,PriceEventName> {
    public PriceEventName unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return PriceEventName.valueOf( v );
    }
    public String marshal(PriceEventName v) throws Exception {
        return v.getStringValue();
    }
}
```